# Is there any long-term drawback of circuit QED systems for Quantum Computation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

As many of you will well know, circuit QED has dominated the QIP scene with astonishing results in the last decade. Almost all industrial approaches use this environment aswell and I could not find any major obstacles in their publications that would prevent this field to succeed the long (or not so long) run for the first Quantum Computer.

In comparison to that, other fields do not show that much progress by far as I'd say. Nonetheless, there are still plenty of approaches, so as I guess, there has to be at least one or some point(s) that prevent(s) circuit QED to just finish the game in the next decade or so.

If anyone of you has enough insight into circuit QED experimentally and could tell me what the biggest limitations are, I'd fascinated to hear that.

Thanks a lot. 
Pascal